# Error in deployment on JBoss - Swagger for Java Guice Jersey

Tags: java, rest, guice, swagger, jersey-1.0

I am trying to integrate Swagger with my Java REST services for generating documentation. I am using Jersey - guice for my REST service with Dependency Injection. The Jersey version is 1.18.2. I am using JBOSS 5.1.2 for deployment. 
Our setup is a little different than the sample projects. We use Jersey as a listener rather than a servlet. 
My web.xml looks like this -

com.mitchell.services.estimatehelper.ioc.GuiceServletConfig

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have a GuiceServletConfig like this -

com.mitchell.services.estimatehelper.ioc.GuiceServletConfig

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The AppInjector is as below -

public class AppInjector extends ServletModule{

```
protected void configureServlets() {

    bind(ServletContainer.class).in(Singleton.class);
    final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");

    params.put("javax.ws.rs.Application", Application.class.getName());
    params.put("jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl", "true");

    ReflectiveJaxrsScanner scanner = new ReflectiveJaxrsScanner();
    scanner.setResourcePackage(getClass().getPackage().getName());
    ScannerFactory.setScanner(scanner);

    bind(EstimateController.class);

    bind(EstimateHelper.class)
            .to(EstimateHelperImpl.class);

    serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);
}
```

}

When I try to deploy this, the scanner throws a below exception

2014-12-22 12:58:40,573 ERROR [STDERR] (RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1) SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding.
2014-12-22 12:58:40,573 ERROR [STDERR] (RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1) SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5 or earlier.
2014-12-22 12:58:40,573 ERROR [STDERR] (RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1) SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version 1.6.x. or 2.0.x
2014-12-22 12:58:40,573 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/estimate-helper-rs-1.0.0]] (RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.mitchell.services.estimatehelper.ioc.GuiceServletConfig
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:279)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:252)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:265)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.ReflectiveJaxrsScanner.(ReflectiveJaxrsScanner.scala:21)
    at com.mitchell.services.estimatehelper.ioc.AppInjector.configureServlets(AppInjector.java:30)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.configure(ServletModule.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)

After researching this further, I realized that this error is due to the  logging libraries which are used by JBoss. 
The error is 
**Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.mitchell.services.estimatehelper.ioc.GuiceServletConfig
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:**

Is there anything that I can do to fix this?? Please help!!

Thanks,
SDD

Answer (score 0):

Check the dependencies if your Application.

Swagger-Core uses SLF4J 1.6.3 and it seems like you have a dependency that overrides it to version 1.5.5 or lower.

If you're using maven, you can see the effective dependencies using `mvn dependency:list` and to see which dependency pulls in the older version use `mvn depdendency:tree`.

Again, if you're using maven, you can either use `<exclusions>` to remove older SLF4J dependency from the one pulling it in, or explicitly add the dependency to your own pom.xml.

If you're using other build tools (gradle and so on), I imagine they have similar helper tools to see where the older version of SLF4J is coming from.

Comment: Thanks! I am using maven, but when I check the maven dependencies there is no dependency on SLF4J. I believe it is the JBoss which has a dependency on SLF4J. Not sure if anything can be done for that.

Comment: There has to be at least one SLF4J dependency because swagger-core pulls it in.